# cout before return shows much different number than in main

Tags: c++

```
double Najkraci(vector<Tocka> v){
    static vector<Tocka> a;
    static int broj = 0;
    int i;
    static double najmanja = 0;
    if (broj == 0) { //pocinjemo od rubne tocke
        for(std::vector<Tocka>::iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it){
            if (it->x < min) {min = it->x; temp = *it;}
        }
        a.push_back(temp);
    }
    if (a.size() == v.size()) {cout <<najmanja; return najmanja;}
    i = 0;
    min = 1000;
    najmanja = najmanja + min;
    a.push_back(temp);
    //cout << "Hrebak";
    //cout << v.size() << ","<< a.size() << endl;
    broj++;
    najmanja = najmanja + Najkraci(v);
}

int main(){
    int n,i;
    double a,b;
    vector<Tocka> t;
    cin >> n;

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b;
        Tocka temp(a,b);
        t.push_back(temp);
    }
    cout << "Najkraci put:" << Najkraci(t);

    return 0;
}
```

Code is messy and probably doesn't work what it's supposed to, but my question is very simple. `cout` before return in function `Najkraci` shows much different number than in `main`. What is wrong? I removed some code because it didn't allow me to post.

Comment: You aren't returning a value from `Najkraci`.  Turn up your compiler warnings.

Comment: You don't have a return statement on all paths through that function.  That leads to undefined behaviour.  Your compiler should warn you about this (if it doesn't, then you need to enable compiler warnings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem of design in your recursive function. The return statement should be at the end of your function.

Otherwise only the last call to `Najkraci` with return a `double` value. All other calls are not returning any value since you hace already pass the return statement.

```
double Najkraci(vector<Tocka> v){
    static vector<Tocka> a;
    static int broj = 0;
    int i;
    static double najmanja = 0;
    if (broj == 0) { 
        for(std::vector<Tocka>::iterator it = v.begin() ; it != v.end(); ++it){
            if (it->x < min) {min = it->x; temp = *it;}
        }
        a.push_back(temp);
    }

    if (a.size() != v.size()) {
        i = 0;
        min = 1000;
        najmanja = najmanja + min;
        a.push_back(temp);
        //cout << "Hrebak";
        //cout << v.size() << ","<< a.size() << endl;
        broj++;
        najmanja = najmanja + Najkraci(v);
    }

    cout <<najmanja;
    return najmanja;
}
```

Comment: it's recursive function, return is in if statement

Comment: thanks, really stupid mistake, happens when you look in code too long